# Summation of numbers in a list

Tags: matlab, list, date, time, sum

I have a long list of precipitation data in a txt file on this form:

> 50810,200301110422,0.1
>
> 50810,200301110422,0.1
>
> 50810,200301110422,0.1
>
> 50810,200301110423,0.1
>
> 50810,200301110423,0.1
>
> 50810,200301110423,0.1

50810 is the station number

200301110422/23 is the date and time

0.1 is the amount of precipitation in mm.

One txt file covers one year, and everytime there is more than one line With the same date and time I want to sum the precipitation.

So, in this case I want the outcome to be:

> 50810,200301110422,0.3
>   50810,200301110423,0.3

I already know how to read the txt file and make a New one. I just need something to put in the matlab code to compress the lines With the same date and time.

Any suggestions on how to do this??

Comment: Perhaps post some of your code so far.

Comment: K, so one way to go is to  `index = find(strcmp(DateArray, '200301110422'))` which will give you the index of all the 200301110422 dates, you can then simply apply a sum to those indexes on your precipitation. The problem is you want it to iterate so you don't have to manually fill in all the dates. Here I suggest you smarten up and think of a simple way to do it. If your date increase by 1 each time, you can convert it `str2num` and +1 then `num2str` back and make it into a variable. Cellfun or loop it to get the result.

Answer (score -1):

I presume you mean same Station and Date Time so you can sum the precipitation by location?

Iterate though each line and do a split to break each line into it's elements. E.g.:

```
If previous Station & Date Time = current Station & Date Time then
    add the value.
else
    save what you got to your new text file and proceed to the next.
```

OR

Copy the structure into a LIST and use some LinQ on it.

OR

Really, you'd want to chuck all this info into a SQL table and then use some aggregate queries on the table. I'd probably go down the SQL route, personally, as it makes it easier to re-extract and manipulate later on.

Comment: With the SQL option, you'll open up your options to dazzle your piers with some great reporting / grouping.

You can probably achivee the same with Linq but I'm not too clever on Linq